# How to safely Create and Free multiple objects in Delphi

Tags: delphi

How should you safely create and free multiple objects?

Basically, this sort of thing:

```
  newOrderSource := TWebNewOrderSource.Create();
  twData := TTWData.Create();
  webData := TWebData.Create();

  try
    //do stuff
  finally
    newOrderSource.Free();
    twData.Free();
    webData.Free();
  end;
```

In this case, the second and third create commands aren't safe, as they work with a database.  Should I just put all the Creates in the try block and check if they are assigned before I call free on them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this with one try block if you assign nil to the variables first like,

```
newOrderSource := nil;
twData := nil;
webData := nil;
try
  newOrderSource := TWebNewOrderSource.Create();    
  twData := TTWData.Create();    
  webData := TWebData.Create();    

  //do stuff    
finally    
  webData.Free();    
  twData.Free();    
  newOrderSource.Free();    
end;
```

This works because `Free()` checks `Self` for `nil`.

Comment: I was posting a very similar answer, one minor change would be to put `newOrderSource := TWebNewOrderSource.Create();` before the try, and ditch the `newOrderSource := nil;`.

Comment: That works too and removes one unneeded assignment but I favored simplicity and consistency in this case because it is highly unlikely saving the assignment would make much a difference if "do stuff" calls into a database.

Comment: I use this all the time but regarding to safety, you should note that, compared to OP's original code, this protects you from exceptions raised in any one constructor but **not** from exceptions raised while freeing the objects. If you are paranoïd about that, your only option is to have as many try/finally's as there are objects (or have them implement interfaces and let them go out of scope).

Comment: @Lieven, if you are really paranoid, make sure no destructor ever raise an exception.  If an exception is raised in a destructor, the object being "destroyed" won't be freed. FreeNotification won't kick in either (as you usually call inherited last in a destructor), so some object might end up pointing to a now invalid and partially freed item. So as far as I'm concerned, exceptions raised from destructor are a way more critical failure than the small memory leak they can create in a situation like this one.

Comment: +1 - I would have never occurred to me that you could call Free() on a nil object!

Comment: @Ken Bourassa - you are preaching to the choir :), I'm not that paranoïd and I also consider an unhandled exception thrown from a destructor something to be dealt with immediately but **it is something to be aware of**. Only the developer knows what objects really positively must be freed no matter what (file handles, transactions, resources in general...). If you do have a case like that, I would recommend to protect it with its own `try...finally`

Comment: @Leonardo If an exception is raised in a constructor then the destructor is run so that the partially constructor object can be tidied up. When this happens any uncreated object members will be `nil` because Delphi initialises all memory to zero which happens to be the same as nil. This is why you don't need to protect each call to Free with an `if Assigned()`. It is also why you call Free rather than Destroy.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for that information. I've been working with Delphi for about, oh I don't know, fifteen years now? and still learning every day.

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera: seriously just check the RTL sources Free is just something like "if Self <> Nil then Destroy".

Comment: @az01 - checking for 'Self <> nil' is not the part that surprises me. The fact that you *can invoke a method* from a *nil object* at all I found surprising. That's some nifty compiler magic.

Comment: @Leonardo `Free` is not a virtual method so the compiler generates a normal function call passing `Self` as a parameter. It is just like passing `nil` as the first parameter of a procedure that takes TObject, it just looks a bit funky.

Comment: @chuckj - I understand the mechanism. It doesn't make it less nice and surprising, you know. You try to do that in Java or C++.

Answer (score 13):

As I'm sure everyone knows, the standard way to manage an object is like this:

```
A := TMyObject.Create;
try
  A.DoSomething;
finally
  A.Free;
end;
```

If there is an exception in `TMyObject.Create` then the destructor will be called and then the exception raised. In that case `A` will not be assigned to.

When you have multiple objects you can repeat the pattern:

```
A := TMyObject.Create;
try
  B := TMyObject.Create;
  try
    A.DoSomething;
    B.DoSomething;
  finally
    B.Free;
  end;
finally
  A.Free;
end;
```

This very quickly becomes a mess and hence the question.

A standard trick is to take advantage of the fact that `Free` can safely be called on a `nil` object reference.

```
A := nil;
B := nil;
try
  A := TMyObject.Create;
  B := TMyObject.Create;
  A.DoSomething;
  B.DoSomething;
finally
  B.Free;
  A.Free;
end;
```

This does have the minor weakness that it is not resilient to exceptions being raised in `B.Free` but it is not unreasonable to regard this as a failure condition that can be ignored. Destructors should not raise exceptions. If they do then your system is probably broken irredeemably.

This pattern above can become a little messy as more objects are added so I personally use the following helper methods.

```
procedure InitialiseNil(var Obj1); overload;
procedure InitialiseNil(var Obj1, Obj2); overload;
procedure InitialiseNil(var Obj1, Obj2, Obj3); overload;

procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj1); overload;
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj1, Obj2); overload;
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj1, Obj2, Obj3); overload;
```

In fact my code has versions with even more parameters. For ease of maintenance this code is all automatically generated from a short Python script.

These methods are implemented in the obvious way, e.g.

```
procedure FreeAndNil(var Obj1, Obj2);
var
  Temp1, Temp2: TObject;
begin
  Temp1 := TObject(Obj1);
  Temp2 := TObject(Obj2);
  Pointer(Obj1) := nil;
  Pointer(Obj2) := nil;
  Temp1.Free;
  Temp2.Free;
end;
```

This allows us to re-write the sample above like this:

```
InitialiseNil(A, B);
try
  A := TMyObject.Create;
  B := TMyObject.Create;
  A.DoSomething;
  B.DoSomething;
finally
  FreeAndNil(B, A);
end;
```

Comment: Couldn't you have your helper methods receive an array of values so you could pass an arbitrary number of objects to them?

Comment: @Jerry That would work too but I preferred not to use open array syntax at this point. My reasoning is that these functions are written once and never modified. So I care less about duplication than I would in living code that is modified. The motivation is so that the calling code is cleaner and that is the code that gets modified.